# Where not via join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `product` table and a `line_items` table.

A `product` has_and_belongs_to_many line_items via the join table `product_line_items`.

**How do I do a query which can return me all the products which don't appear in the line_item ID of 6?**

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
Product.joins(:line_items).where.not(line_items: {id: 6})
```

But this is returning me no rows as it's doing an inner join and actually none of my products are in any line items right now...

Is there a simple way to write this or do I have to do a left join query?

So I want to find all products that didn't appear in line_item ID 6 (including products that never appeared in a line item at all!). Is there an easy query syntax I didn't spot?

Thanks, v. much.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by line_item id of 6? I suppose you have a line_items_products table which records all association between products and line_items. Is line item id of 3 the line_item_id field or the uniq id field of the table doing association ?

Comment: @Typpex Hi, yeah as I mentioned I have a product_line_items table which is the join table. The line_item.id of 6 relates specifically to the line_items table ID column. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would like to do this as the ID of line_items_products is kind of useless for you.

But you could do this in active record:

```
Product.joins(line_items).where("line_items_products.id <> ?", 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I for anyone interested I ended up doing:

```
Product.where.not(id: line_item_6.products.map(&:id))
```

Were `line_item_6` would be a reference to the `line_item` model that has ID of 6.